# how do I find the number of xml children in AS3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, children

so live docs says this for calling .lenght() on an XML object

> For XML objects, this method always
>   returns the integer 1. The length()
>   method of the XMLList class returns a
>   value of 1 for an XMLList object that
>   contains only one value.

i called it on an xml that looked like this:

```
<xml>
<picture>1</picture>
<picture>2</picture>
</xml>
```

i tried myXML.lenght() and it reallt returned 1. how do i get the number of children in my xml?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
var length:int = myXML.children().length();
```

Also, this is the method I use to make sure the children are really Elements, and not just Text Nodes.

```
    public static function getNumberChildElements(node:XML):int{
        var count:int = 0;
        for (var i:int=0; i<node.children().length(); i++){
            if (node.children()[i].nodeKind() == "element")
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var totPictures=myXML.picture.length();
trace(totPictures); //2
```

Answer (score 0):

Also `myXML.*.length()` will work

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right way.

```
var totItems:int = myXML.elements().children().length();
trace(totItems);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
var num:int = myXml.length();
```

Comment: as i said in the post- i tried it already. well, it gives me 1 even with 2 children...

Comment: looks like it's counting your <xml> node, not your <picture> nodes. try myXML.children().length().