# Looking to return the number of images loaded using loadermax xml image loader

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, trace

I can't find an exact way to get an number returned, "trace(event.target.content);" returns all of the content of the xml doc, but Im looking for, in this case "3"

```
function xmlCompleteHandler1(event:LoaderEvent):void
{
 trace(event.target.content);

    buildLoaderMax();
}
```

I get this

```
    <data>   <LoaderMax name="gallery">
        <ImageLoader url="my_images/gallery/mynameis/1386009931.jpg"/>
        <ImageLoader url="my_images/gallery/mynameis/1389667752.jpg"/>
        <ImageLoader url="my_images/gallery/mynameis/1388092661.jpg"/>
</LoaderMax> </data>
```

Here is the loader

```
var queue:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader(String(url1)+String(username1)+"_myfile.xml",{name:"xmlDoc",
    maxConnections:1,
    estimatedBytes:500,
    onComplete:xmlCompleteHandler1
    });
    queue.load();
```

Comment: `trace((event.target.content as XML).data.LoaderMax.ImageLoader.length)` ?

Comment: @Vesper you mean `length()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655514/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-xml-children-in-as3

Comment: trace((event.target.content as XML).data.LoaderMax.ImageLoader.length()) returns 0

Comment: Maybe then `trace((event.target.content as XML).data.LoaderMax.children().length())`? I'm inept when it comes to XML in AS3, so this is just a little more than a guess.

Comment: still retiring a 0, but I try this trace(event.target.content  as XML )and get the full xml data again. so I put trace(event.target.content  as XML )into function imageCompleteHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void and get a series "null" but they match the correct number of images loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example 100% works:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

var myXML:XML;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("data.xml"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlCompleteHandler1);

function xmlCompleteHandler1(event:Event):void
{
    myXML = new XML(event.target.data );
    trace( myXML.LoaderMax.ImageLoader.length() ); // 3
}
```

Comment: I don't think the myXML.LoaderMax.ImageLoader.length can be traced when the LoaderMax is not being used to load anything? no sure..

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up tracing the images after they are pushed to and array
trace(galleryArr.length );

```
function onGalleryLoaded(e:Event):void
{

    var imageX:int = 0;
    var imageY:int = 0;



    {

        var indvPicHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
               trace(galleryArr.length );

{
```